# How do I fix this error with my arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I am using tikz to generate sine and cosine graphs with arrows at the ends of each curve. The arrows appear fine for the sine curve, but not so for the cosine curve. Why does this occur and how do I fix it?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,>=latex,x=0.5cm,y=2.0cm]
            \draw[<->,thick,domain=-4*pi:4*pi,samples=250,color=red] plot (\x,{sin(\x r)}) node[below right] {\footnotesize \textcolor{red}{$y= \sin(x)$}};
            \draw[<->,thick,domain=-4*pi:4*pi,samples=250,color=blue] plot (\x,{cos(\x r)}) node[right] {\footnotesize \textcolor{blue}{$y= \cos(x)$}};
            \draw[->,thick] (-14,0) -- (14,0) node[below left]{\footnotesize $x$};
            \draw[->,thick] (0,-2) -- (0,2) node[below right]{\footnotesize $y$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Graphs of sine and cosine}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It occurs because the plot is made up of many (c. 250) short curves segments and the arrow tip is only applied to the last curve segment.  For the sine curve the final segments point in roughly the same direction, whereas for cosine they are varying rapidly.  A crude fix is to draw the arrows separately.

Comment: a nicer fix is to do `domain=-3.9*pi:3.9*pi` for the cosine

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When PGF puts an arrowhead on a line it "backs-up" along the last path segment so that the end of the arrow tip is at the end of path. As plots are (usually) lots of small straight lines PGF backs up along the last straight line segment.

When the gradient of the line segments are changing relatively slowly (as in the end points of the sine curve in the MWE) it looks OK. Otherwise (i.e., the end points of the cosine curve in the MWE) it does not.

Although PGF 3.0 adds lots of fancy features for bending and flexing arrows, I think the simplest solution is to lengthen the first and final line-segments. Fortunately this is easy by using the `shorten >` and `shorten <` keys with *negative* values.

```
\documentclass[border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending}
\begin{document} 
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,>=latex,x=0.5cm,y=2.0cm]
            \draw[<->,thick,domain=-4*pi:4*pi,samples=250,color=red] plot (\x,{sin(\x r)}) node[below right] {\footnotesize \textcolor{red}{$y= \sin(x)$}};
            \draw[<->,thick,domain=-4*pi:4*pi,samples=250,color=blue,
shorten >=-4pt, shorten <=-4pt] 
plot (\x,{cos(\x r)}) node[right=5pt] {\footnotesize \textcolor{blue}{$y= \cos(x)$}};
            \draw[->,thick] (-14,0) -- (14,0) node[above left]{\footnotesize $x$};
            \draw[->,thick] (0,-2) -- (0,2) node[below right]{\footnotesize $y$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the arrow head in Ti*k*Z is not appended to the line but super-positioned over its end. As the curvature at the end of you cosine curve is quite big, this  results in your ugly result (the direction of the arrow is correct...).

I added two possible hacks you could try. The first is just shortening the graph to a section with lower curvature (green line) and the other plots an invisible graph for y=1 with blue arrow heads.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,>=latex,x=0.5cm,y=2.0cm]
        \draw[<->,thick,domain=-4*pi:4*pi,samples=250,color=red] plot (\x,{sin(\x r)}) node[above right] {\footnotesize $y= \sin(x)$};
        \draw[-,thick,domain=-4*pi:4*pi,samples=250,color=blue] plot (\x,{cos(\x r)}) node[right] {\footnotesize $y= \cos(x)$};
        \draw[<->,>={LaTeX[]},draw opacity=0, domain=-4.1*pi:4.1*pi, color=blue] plot (\x, 1);
        \draw[<->,thick,domain=-3.9*pi:3.9*pi,samples=250,color=green] plot (\x,-{cos(\x r)}) node[right] {\footnotesize $y= -\cos(x)$};
        \draw[->,thick] (-14,0) -- (14,0) node[below left]{\footnotesize $x$};
        \draw[->,thick] (0,-2) -- (0,2) node[below right]{\footnotesize $y$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Graphs of sine and cosine}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]